# bitwise comparison in bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table with columns shaped as following:

```
| ID | name | A | B | C | D |
|  1 |  foo | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|  2 |  bar | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|  3 |  foo | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|  4 |  bar | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

A, B, C and D are bit columns.

I need to get the name values of the rows of which there at least two and that both have at least one identical bit column set to true. the result set I want to get for the given example is as following:

```
| name | 
|  foo |
```

I can do the following:

```
SELECT l.name
FROM dummy l
INNER JOIN dummy r ON l.name = r.name
WHERE (l.A = 1 AND r.A = 1) 
OR (l.B = 1 AND r.B = 1) 
OR (l.C = 1 AND r.C = 1)
OR (l.D = 1 AND r.D = 1)
GROUP BY l.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this gets unreadable soon since the table is massive. I was wondering if there was a bitwise solution to solve this

Comment: What does your result set have to do with the sample data?

Comment: I don't understand the expected result. I would kind of understand it if `A` was `1` rather than `D`.

Comment: I removed some distracting details

Comment: But they all have at least 1 bit column set to true.  Question is not clear.

Comment: At lease of one bit columns the value needs to be set to true and the name needs to be identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your data model is wrong. It feels like A-D represent the same "type" of thing and so the data *ought* to be represented using a single column that *contains* the data values A-D and (if necessary) one column to store the 1 or 0, with separate *rows* for each A-D value. (But then, of course, we can use the presence of a row to indicate a 1 and the absence of the row to represent a 0).

We can use `UNPIVOT` to get this "better" structure for the data and then the query becomes *trivial*:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, name char(3) not null, A bit not null, B bit not null,
                                                          C bit not null, D bit not null)
insert into @t(ID,name,A,B,C,D) values
(1,'foo',1,0,0,1),
(2,'bar',0,0,1,1),
(3,'foo',1,1,0,0),
(4,'bar',1,1,0,0)

;With ProperLayout as (
    select ID,Name,Property,Value
    from @t t
        unpivot (Value for Property in (A,B,C,D)) u
    where Value = 1
)
select name,Property
from ProperLayout
group by name,Property
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
name Property
---- ---------
foo  A
```

(Note also that the top of my script is not much different in size to the sample data in your question but has the massive benefit that it's *runnable*)

Comment: the data model is indeed a mess, but it's from a client, and changing it is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: @martijn - even if you cannot fix the data model, this is the usual approach I'd take in this situation - first build up one or more CTEs that turns it into *the data model it ought to have been* and then you can use all of the normal SQL tools at their best strength. I.e. in SQL, we don't do bitwise ops - we do grouping and aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

In similar way you could also use *Apply*  opertaor

```
SELECT a.name FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (name, 'A', A), (name, 'B', B), (name, 'C', C), (name, 'D', D)
)a(name , names , value)
WHERE a.value = 1 
GROUP BY a.name, a.Names, a.value
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Was just about to post this method.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you seem to want:

```
SELECT l.name
FROM dummy l
GROUP BY l.name
HAVING SUM( CAST(A as int) ) >= 2 OR
       SUM( CAST(B as int) ) >= 2 OR
       SUM( CAST(C as int) ) >= 2 OR
       SUM( CAST(D as int) ) >= 2 ;
```

This is based on the description.  I don't know what the same result row has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to read.  It is just long.
This would be more efficient:

```
SELECT distinct l.name
FROM       dummy l
INNER JOIN dummy r 
   ON l.name = r.name
  and l.id < r.id 
  and (    (l.A = 1 AND r.A = 1) 
        OR (l.B = 1 AND r.B = 1) 
        OR (l.C = 1 AND r.C = 1)
        OR (l.D = 1 AND r.D = 1) 
      )
order by l.name
```

You could build it up reading sys.columns

I don't think TSQL has any bitwise operators.